# window.parent = null to prevent access?

Tags: javascript, cross-domain

We all know about this cross-origin stuff and how to prevent access on window.parent from iframes and stuff.

But wouldn't it be enough to have an `window.parent = null;` before any third-party code runs, so any access up there would fail?

Comment: the outer window.parent is not the same as the inner one. so, no, that doesn';t make sense.

Comment: `window.parent` should be read-only

Comment: yeah i was talking about the inner one..

Comment: tried to override it, it works for me in chrome.

Comment: Couldn’t it still be accessed with `window.top`?